# "No such file or directory" error when running a shell command via a script on Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins

I am able to execute a shell command directly on Jenkins. However, when I try to run the same command via a script, it gives me the following error:

```
[test_pytest] $ C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -xe C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins1276820232141896422.sh
+ C:/ProgramData/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/Pytest_test/test.sh
C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins1276820232141896422.sh: line 2: C:/ProgramData/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/Pytest_test/test.sh: No such file or directory
```

I have this file avilable in folder:

[image: the path of the file test.sh]

Comment: Aren't you on windows? Are you using Gitbash like utility to run shell script?

Comment: Yes I am on windows. I am using C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe to run shell script.

Answer (score 0):

### 1.

from the picture,the file test.sh is a text file

you should first checkout extension of the file, make sure it's **Shell Script**, not the **Text Document**

see for example [here](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/change-file-extension-in-windows-10.html#:%7E:text=you%20can%20run.-,How%20to%20Change%20File%20Extension%20in%20Windows%2010,-Now%2C%20you%20can)

- Open Windows File Explorer
- Click the "View" tab. Tick the "File name extensions" option
- and then right-click the file, choose rename, and enter the new file extension

### 2.

And try again on your jenkins.